# How to load initialVewController using xibs in Swift 4 ? (I don't want to set initialViewController with StoryBoard)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios11, swift4

I want to load initial view controller with xibs not with storyboard. As I am migrating objective c project to swift 4. Can any one have any idea to resolve this issue ?

Comment: This is very well known and well documented here. Search before asking, please. Don't make us do your research for you.

Answer (score 0):

To load xib as the initial view controller instead of a storyboard, you can achieve this as implied in the following sample code,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    loadInitialVC()
    return true
}

func loadInitialVC() {
    let testVC = TestNibViewController(nibName: "TestNibViewController", bundle: nil) as? TestNibViewController
    window?.rootViewController = testVC
}
```

You might face issue when using the xib which I faced while trying, so if you found any issue like "Loaded nib but the view outlet was not set" do as in the image attached.
[image]
[image]

Comment: i am getting this error after using this solution

 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle </Users/shubhamjain/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4840E2AD-9393-442E-B079-BD3FF893FFFD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A4105540-A128-4A9B-8337-985724F3FF2B/SwiftDemo.app> (loaded)'

Comment: You have asked to load a xib, but now you are trying to open "Main" storyboard as per the error says ?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your `Info.plist`: delete the **Main storyboard file base name** key and add a **Main nib file base name** key with the base name (without `.xib`) of your initial XIB.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution of my question , the correct way to load a xib as initialViewController in swift 4

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
     launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

   self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
   let testVC = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil) as? MyViewController
   let navigationBar = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: testVC!)
   window?.rootViewController = navigationBar
   window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   return true
}
```

Hope this solution will help of others too.

Comment: some one voted this solution with negative votes. Before the solution i tried to find the solution on various links including stack overflow, but i did not get the correct solution, but when i found the solution, someone voted negative without explaining his reason.Please share the reason too, that will help others why u voted neg and his wisdom will be appreciated then.